Translates of a set of positive Lebesgue measure cover $\mathbb{R}$?
Let $E$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$. Does some countable union of translates of $E$ cover $\mathbb{R}$?
My intuition is that $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered with countable translates of $E$ except a set of measure zero. Clearly, if $E$ contains an interval, its translates will cover $\mathbb{R}$. So the example that I tried to make work was the set of irrationals, but I don’t know how to show that countable union of its translates cannot cover $\mathbb{R}$.
Any hint or solution is appreciated.

Let $E$ be  fat Cantor set (i.e. a Cantor like set of positive measure). Then $E$ has no interior. If $\mathbb R=\bigcup_n (E+x_n)$ then Baire Category Theorem implies that $E+x_n$ has an intetior point for some  $n$ which is a  contradiction. [Note that $E$ is closed and hence $E+x_n$ is closed for each $n$].

It would be nice to mention that $E$ is closed.

OK. Thanks for the suggestion.  @AndréCaldas
